# change the class of in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to go away from our current according style menu and use jquery in it's place.  The problem is our curent code uses values that we pass in on the query string to tell the menu which section should be open and what item in that section should be highilghted.  I've been trying to work with jquery to accomplish this but i'm new to jquery and am stumbling.  I've seen a lot of examples out there of according style menu's, but none allow me to pass in the section and the row to hightlight.

So i've found a simple according style menu that uses jquery and i'm thinking that if i have an unordered list, somethign like this

```
<ul id="accordion">
        <li>
            <div>
                Sports</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Golf</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cricket</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                Technology</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="c23">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                Latest</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Obama</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Iran Election</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Health Care</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I should, with jquery be able to do a $('accordion').find('c23') and be able to slideup this section and hightligh the href.. but i can't figure out the code to do it... Here is what i have so far to get the according effect

```
 $("#accordion > li > div").click(function () {

            if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                $('#accordion ul').slideUp(300);
            }
            $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
        });
```

this is some code i found at http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/09/create-accordion-menu-jquery.html...

Anyway.. was hoping someone descent at jquery would be able to help me out.

Thanks
shannon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is largely that you're missing the "#"'s in your find code and that you're not accessing the parent element. Here's a fixed example:

```
var wanted_id = 'c23'; // This is the bit you'd get off the querystring.

$(document).ready(function ( ) {
    $("#accordion > li > div").click(function () {

            if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                $('#accordion ul').slideUp(300);
            }
            $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });

    // This is the bit that handles the highlighting and automatic opening
    $('#accordion').find('#'+wanted_id).css('background-color','blue'); 
    $('#accordion').find('#'+wanted_id).parent( ).parent( ).slideToggle(300);

});
```

​You can test this at a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DkZYb/1/

Comment: if i wanted to continue up to and do something to the div tag that holds the text Technology, what would the syntax be.  I tried $('#accordion').find('#' + wanted_id).parent().parent().find('div').css('color','red');

Comment: never mind. i figured it out. i just saw you link to jsfiddle.. and was able to use that to step my way through it...  $('#accordion').find('#' + wanted_id).parent().parent().parent().find('div').find('div').css('background-color', 'yellow')... thanks again for the help

Comment: No worries. By the way, it might be better to assign a CSS class to the highlighted object instead of assigning CSS properties directly. It makes it much easier to update templates down the line. Instead of the `.css(...)` you'd use `$('#accordion').find('#'+wanted_id).addClass('highlighted');`

Answer (score 0):

jquery UI Accordion (and probably many other accordion plugins) provide some events that fire whenever the current item is changed in your accordion. You can handle those events and highlight your item there. This is easier, cleaner, etc.

see events section of this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "accordionchange", function(event, ui) {
  $(ui.newContent).find("<item to highlight selector").addClass(".highlighted");
});
```